# Calculating the GROUP BY total in a SharePoint Column

Tags: infopath, list-view, calculated-column, filter

I am trying to do something here, which I do not know if it is possible.  I have a custom list in SharePoint 2010 where the "Course" name is unique.  I am using "Group By" in the view which shows me the totals for each Course (circled in red via screenshot here)

[image]

Am I able to calculate these group by values (in red) in another SharePoint column.  The reason being:  I have another column "Limit" which I want to compare the group by to.  So for instance...I want to compare this new column to my "Limit" column.  And if the new column is greater than or equal to Limit, then my InfoPath form will not allow a submit.

Ultimately, on my InfoPath form, I want to compare two values, the Limit (which I have already) vs each Course's Group By value.  This will be sufficient because each Course is unique.

I'm looking to do this: **When Course = X, the group by value circled in red is populated in a hidden field on an infopath form.** Then I will compare that number to my Limit field.

Please help :) !!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a new connection on infopath and create a validation rule based on the connection to with the count() formula before the submit

if count(connection2[id]) > limit

ok, this would work in infopath 2013, but i don't know if it will work on 2010

1.- I would create a calculated field = for the itemlimit (this will be the filter)

2.- Create a connection to extract the courses

3.- Create a validation rule where

- List item
- Itemlimit Minor than (use a formula)
- insert field or group
- Show advanced view
- change connection  select the field
- filter data
- Course equal to "select field or group"
- change back to main connection
- select the Course field from the main connection
- ok, ok, ok, ok, ok

Comment: I think my problem is I don't want the total count of the entire list I just want the count a specific field (Course) .  So when Course = X (and this will be on my InfoPath form) i want that count.... not the entire count of all the items in the list if that makes sense....